# What library can I use for calc large sparse matrix in Java or Scala?

Tags: java, scala, sparse-matrix, compression

When I use large sparse matrix, it's better to use compressed matrix like CCS, CRS and so on.

I tried to use ScalaNLP, la4j, colc to calc 100,000*100,000 sparse matrix.
There are some problems.

1. Breeze (ScalaNLP/Scalala)

   - it gives me the `CSCMatrix` type which can have 100,000*100,000 size.
   - but the problem is it's under development.
   - so we cannot calc element-wise product of `CSCMatrix` with `CSCMatrix`, like `csc1 :* csc2`.
   - and also you cannot add CSCMatrixes to each other.
2. la4j

   - It has CCSMatrix and CRSMatrix.
   - but when creating (new CCSMatrixFactory).createMatrix(100000, 100000), it occur OutOfMemoryError.
   - The matrix should be zeros, so it should not use large memory spaces.
3. colc

   - It has SparseDoubleMatrix2D.
   - but when creating matrix like new SparseDoubleMatrix2d(100000, 100000), it says IllegalArgumentException: matrix too large.

To calc large sparse matrix, what library can I use?
could you show me the example?

Comment: Have you tried MTJ?  http://matrix-toolkits-java.googlecode.com/svn/branches/0.9.13/javadoc/index.html.  (Note also that there is a more general question on this topic here ... http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2656/recommendations-for-a-usable-fast-java-matrix-library ... though there are no good answers.)

Comment: tried use MTJ. it shows as follows.
scala> val mtx = new CompColMatrix(100000,100000,Array.fill(100000)(Array.fill(100000)))
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. 
there are no ideas except using matlab or python...

Comment: Did you try to figure out **why** it did that?  Are you sure that that is the *right* way to create a sparse matrix?  It seems to me like you are flitting from one product to the next as soon as you experience a problem.

Comment: Array.fill(100000)(Array.fill(100000)) this code will overflow for sure. Populate your sparse matrix in a loop, or use unfolds, or if it's a sparse matrix it should be initialized with zeros by default.

Comment: thanks for your comments. My goal is to create large zeros compress sparse matrix and add some data into this matrix, then calc a little. I still have not understood the usage of MTJ well. will try it. Thanks.

Comment: What is exactly the operation you need to perform with your matrix? Product or element-wise multiplication? Where exactly did Breeze (ScalaNLP) fail? The [Wiki](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/SparseVector) states that sparse matrices should support element-wise multiplication, but [this bug tracker entry](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/issues/26) indicates that it is not implemented yet.

Comment: I think `3. colc` should be `3. Colt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was curious with Breeze, so I looked into the source. It's a bit messy because the operators are all emitted from some println style code generation (!)... But I came up with this:

```
import breeze.linalg.operators.{BinaryOp, OpMulScalar}

object CSCMatrixExtraOps {
  abstract class CSCMatrixCanMulM_M[@specialized (Int, Float, Long, Double) A]
    extends BinaryOp[CSCMatrix[A], CSCMatrix[A], OpMulScalar, CSCMatrix[A]] {

    protected def times(a: A, b: A): A

    protected def zeros  (rows: Int, cols: Int): CSCMatrix[A]
    protected def builder(rows: Int, cols: Int, sz: Int): CSCMatrix.Builder[A]

    final def apply(a: CSCMatrix[A], b: CSCMatrix[A]): CSCMatrix[A] = {
      val rows  = a.rows
      val cols  = a.cols
      require(rows == b.rows, "Matrices must have same number of rows!")
      require(cols == b.cols, "Matrices must have same number of cols!")

      if (cols == 0) return zeros(rows, cols)
```

```
      val res     = builder(rows, cols, math.min(a.activeSize, b.activeSize))
      var ci      = 0
      var acpStop = a.colPtrs(0)
      var bcpStop = b.colPtrs(0)
      while (ci < cols) {
        val ci1 = ci + 1
        var acp = acpStop
        var bcp = bcpStop
        acpStop = a.colPtrs(ci1)
        bcpStop = b.colPtrs(ci1)
        while (acp < acpStop && bcp < bcpStop) {
          val ari = a.rowIndices(acp)
          val bri = b.rowIndices(bcp)
          if (ari == bri) {
            val v = times(a.data(acp), b.data(bcp))
            res.add(ari, ci, v)
            acp += 1
            bcp += 1
          } else if (ari < bri) {
            acp += 1
          } else /* ari > bri */ {
            bcp += 1
          }
        }
        ci = ci1
      }

      res.result()
    }
  }
```

```
  implicit object CSCMatrixCanMulM_M_Int extends CSCMatrixCanMulM_M[Int] {
    protected def times(a: Int, b: Int) = a * b
    protected def zeros(rows: Int, cols: Int) = CSCMatrix.zeros(rows, cols)
    protected def builder(rows: Int, cols: Int, sz: Int) = 
      new CSCMatrix.Builder(rows, cols, sz)
  }

  implicit object CSCMatrixCanMulM_M_Double extends CSCMatrixCanMulM_M[Double] {
    protected def times(a: Double, b: Double) = a * b
    protected def zeros(rows: Int, cols: Int) = CSCMatrix.zeros(rows, cols)
    protected def builder(rows: Int, cols: Int, sz: Int) = 
      new CSCMatrix.Builder(rows, cols, sz)
  }
}
```

---

**Example:**

```
import breeze.linalg._
import CSCMatrixExtraOps._

val m1 = CSCMatrix((0, 0, 0), (0, 5, 0), (0, 0, 10), (0, 13, 0))
val m2 = CSCMatrix((0, 0, 0), (0, 5, 0), (0, 0, 10), (13, 0, 0))
(m1 :* m2).toDenseMatrix
```

Result:

```
0  0   0    
0  25  0    
0  0   100  
0  0   0
```

Comment: It should be _require(a.cols == b.rows)_ and so on. btw your answer help me thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of [la4j](http://la4j.org) library. Let me give you few advices. So, when you created a new CRS/CCS matrix, la4j allocates only 32-lenght array for it (it is a default minimum size). Thus, it can not throw a OOM error (I've just checked it):

```
Matrix a = Matrices.CRS_FACTORY.createMatrix(100000, 100000);
```

But, it is better to use public constructor:

```
Matrix a = new CCSMatrix(100000, 100000);
```

Anyway, if you still getting this error, try to extend your heap size with `-Xmx1024m -Xms512m`.

And what do you mean by "The matrix should be zeros, so it should not use large memory spaces." I'm not sure that I understood it correctly.

BTW, use the last version of la4j: [0.4.0](http://la4j.blogspot.com/2013/06/la4j-040-is-here.html). Probably, issue you found was fixed by [this pull-request](https://github.com/vkostyukov/la4j/pull/40).

Comment: I think he expects the matrix to be small since all it needs to store is the indices and values of the non-zero cells, while the vast majority of cells are zero and need not be stored. If your matrix actually stores a large number of 0-values then it's really not sparse.